# How to rotate Local Axis?

Tags: axis

How can I rotate the Local Axis of an object.

I ran into this problem when I tried to use a downloaded object from the internet and it turned out the angled parts Local Axis stand same way as the Global Axis. Is there an add on or plug in to make it happen?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images and expand your text to help describe what you are working, and to describe the problem. There are many transform orientations available in blender, but what you are asking is unclear as of the current writing.

Comment: maybe what you're looking for is the Affect Only > Origins option in the Options panel (top left of your 3D view)?

Comment: life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the *Transform Affect Only > Origins* option in the *Options* panel (top left of your 3D view), which allows you to move the object's origin and change its orientation:

[image]